# How can I subtract a previous row in sql?

Tags: sql-server, vb6

What should I query if I wanted to subtract the current row to the previous row. I will use it on looping in vb6.
Something Like this:

```
Row
1
2
3
4
5
```

On first loop value 1 will not be deducted because it has no previous row, which is ok.
Next loop value 2 will then be deducted by the previous row which is value 1. And so on until the last row.

How can I achieve this routine?
By SQL query or VB6 code.Any will do.

Comment: Keep in mind there's no such thing as "previous row" in a SQL result set unless you use an "ORDER BY" clause to define the order. Also, you should try to think in terms of sets with relational databases, so I hope someone gives you a set-wise answer (I have to leave now).

Comment: .,yes.but how can I define that in order by clause?thanks...

Comment: Outline (sorry I have to run): define a CTE that uses ORDER BY to choose an order, and then uses [ROW_NUMBER](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to add a column defining the order. Then join the CTE to itself on x.ROWNUM = y.ROWNUM+1, and include x.value-y.value.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Assuming you have an ordering column -- say `id` -- then you can do the following in SQL Server 2012:

```
select col,
       col - coalesce(lag(col) over (order by id), 0) as diff
from t;
```

In earlier versions of SQL Server, you can do almost the same thing using a correlated subquery:

```
select col,
       col - isnull((select top 1 col
                     from t t2
                     where t2.id < t.id
                     order by id desc
                    ), 0)
from t
```

This uses `isnull()` instead of `coalesce()` because of a "bug" in SQL Server that evaluates the first argument twice when using `coalesce()`.

You can also do this with `row_number()`:

```
with cte as (
      select col, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     )
select t.col, t.col - coalesce(tprev.col, 0) as diff
from cte t left outer join
     cte tprev
     on t.seqnum = tprev.seqnum + 1;
```

All of these assume that you have some column for specifying the ordering.  It might be an `id`, or a creation date or something else.  SQL tables are inherently unordered, so there is no such thing as a "previous row" without a column specifying the ordering.

Comment: What if he doesn't have an ordering column? ROW_NUMBER?

Comment: Is there a particular reason to use COALESCE on the LAG, rather than the 'default' argument to the LAG function?

Comment: @Volodya . . . Habit.  `lag()` and `lead()` take several arguments.  I can remember the first two easily -- the column and the offset.

Comment: There's a table `cte` created, but the reference beneath it is to table `t`. Fix?

Comment: @fortune_p . . . Oops.  Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Lot of thx! It helped me!

Answer (score 0):

Using Cursor:

```
CREATE TABLE t (id int)
INSERT INTO t
VALUES(1)

INSERT INTO t
VALUES(2)

INSERT INTO t
VALUES(3)

INSERT INTO t
VALUES(4) 

DECLARE @actual int; 
DECLARE @last int;
DECLARE @sub int; 

SET @last = 0; 

DECLARE sub_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT *
    FROM t OPEN sub_cursor 
    FETCH NEXT
    FROM sub_cursor INTO @actual; 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    SELECT @sub = @actual - @last print cast(@actual AS nvarchar) + '-' + cast(@last AS nvarchar) + '=' + cast(@sub AS nvarchar)
    SET @last = @actual 
    FETCH NEXT FROM sub_cursor INTO @actual; 
END

DROP TABLE t 
CLOSE sub_cursor; DEALLOCATE sub_cursor;
```