# SQL Server - deducting from available credit

Tags: sql-server

I have invoicing solution that uses Azure SQL to store and calculate invoice data. I have been requested to provide 'credit' functionality so rather than recovering customers charges, the totals are deducted from an amount of available credit and reflected in the invoice (solution xyz may have 1500 worth of charges, but deducted from available credit of 10,000 means its effectively zero'd and leaves 8,500 credit remaining ).  Unfortunately after several days I haven't been able to work out how to do this.

I am able to get a list of items and their costs from sql easily:

| invoice_id | contact_id | solution_id | total | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 202104-015 | 52 | 10000 | 30317.27 | 2021-05-22 |
| 202104-015 | 52 | 10001 | 2399.90 | 2021-05-22 |
| 202104-015 | 52 | 10005 | 8302.27 | 2021-05-22 |
| 202104-015 | 52 | 10060 | 3625.22 | 2021-05-22 |
| 202104-015 | 52 | 10111 | 22.87 | 2021-05-22 |
| 202104-015 | 52 | 10115 | 435.99 | 2021-05-22 |

I have another table that shows the credit available for the given contact:

| id | credit_id | owner_id | total_applied | date_applied |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | C00001 | 52 | 500000.00 | 2021-05-14 |

I have tried using the following SQL statement, based on another stackoverflow question to [subtract from the previous row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17560829/how-can-i-subtract-a-previous-row-in-sql/17560933), thinking each row would then reflect the remaining credit:

```
Select 
    invoice_id,
    solution_id
    sum(total) as 'total',
    cr.total_remaining - coalesce(lag(total)) over (order by s.solution_id), 0) as credit_available,
    date
from
    invoices
left join credits cr on
    cr.credit_id = 'C00001'
```

Whilst this does subtract, it only subtracts from the row above it, not all of the rows above it:

| invoice_id | solution_id | total | credit_available | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 202104-015 | 10000 | 30317.27 | 500000.00 | 2021-05-22 |
| 202104-015 | 10001 | 2399.90 | 469682.73 | 2021-05-22 |
| 202104-015 | 10005 | 8302.27 | 497600.10 | 2021-05-22 |
| 202104-015 | 10060 | 3625.22 | 491697.73 | 2021-05-22 |
| 202104-015 | 10111 | 22.87 | 496374.78 | 2021-05-22 |
| 202104-015 | 10115 | 435.99 | 499977.13 | 2021-05-22 |

I've also tried various queries with a mess of case statements.

Im at the point where I am contemplating using powershell or similar to do the task instead (loop through each solution, check if there is enough available credit, update a deduction table, goto next etc) but I'd rather keep it all in SQL if I can.

Anyone have some pointers for this beginner?

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty complex scenario. I sadly cannot spend the time to offer a complete solution here. I do can provide you with tips and points of attention here:

- Be sure to determine the actual remaining credit based on the *complete* invoice history. If you introduce filtering (in a WHERE-clause, for example, or by including joins with other tables), the results should not be affected by it. You should probably pre-calculate the available credit per invoice detail record in a temporary table or in a CTE and use that data in your main query.
- Make sure that you regard the `date_applied` value of the credit. Before a credit is applied to a customer, that customer should probably have less credit or no credit at all. That should be reflected correctly on historical invoices, I guess.
- Make sure you determine the correct amount of total credit. It is unclear from the information provided in your question how that should be determined/calculated. Is only the latest `total_applied` value from the `credits` table active? Or should all the historical `total_applied` values be summarized to get the total available credit?)
- Include a correct join between your `invoices` table and your `credits` table. Currently, this join is hard coded in your query.
- Also regard actual payments by customers. Payments have effect on the available credit, I assume. Also note that, unless you are OK with a history that changes, you need to regard the payment dates as well (just like the credit change dates).

I'm not sure how you would solve your scenario using PowerShell... I do know for sure, that this can be tackled with SQL.

I cannot say anything about the resulting performance, however. These kinds of calculations surely come with a price tag attached in that regard. If you need high performance, I guess it might be more practical to include columns in your invoices table to physically store the available credit with each invoice detail record.

**Edit**

I have experimented a little with your scenario and your additional comments.

My solution implementation uses two CTEs:

- The first CTE (`cte_invoice_credit_dates`) retrieves the date of the active credit record for specific invoice IDs.
- The second CTE (`cte_contact_invoice_summarized_totals`) calculates the invoice totals of all the invoices of a specific contact. Since you want to summarize on solution detail per invoice as well, I also included the solution ID per invoice in the querying logic.

The main query selects all columns from the `invoices` table and uses the data from the two CTEs to calculate three additional columns in the result set:

- Column `credit_assigned` represents the total assigned credit at the invoice's date.
- Column `summarized_total` shows the contact's cumulative invoice total.
- Column `credit_available` shows the remaining credit.

```sql
WITH
  [cte_invoice_credit_dates] AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
      I.[invoice_id],
      C.[date_applied]
    FROM
      [invoices] AS I
      OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP (1) [date_applied]
                   FROM [credits]
                   WHERE
                     [owner_id] = I.[contact_id] AND
                     [date_applied] <= I.[date]
                   ORDER BY [date_applied] DESC) AS C
  ),
  [cte_contact_invoice_summarized_totals] AS (
    SELECT
      I.[contact_id],
      I.[invoice_id],
      I.[solution_id],
      SUM(H.[total]) AS [total]
    FROM
      [invoices] AS I
      INNER JOIN [invoices] AS H ON
        H.[contact_id] = I.[contact_id] AND
        H.[invoice_id] = I.[invoice_id] AND
        H.[solution_id] <= I.[solution_id] AND
        H.[date] <= I.[date]
    GROUP BY
      I.[contact_id],
      I.[invoice_id],
      I.[solution_id]
  )
SELECT
  I.[invoice_id],
  I.[contact_id],
  I.[solution_id],
  I.[total],
  I.[date],
  COALESCE(C.[total_applied], 0) AS [credit_assigned],
  H.[total] AS [summarized_total],
  COALESCE(C.[total_applied] - H.[total], 0) AS [credit_available]
FROM
  [invoices] AS I
  INNER JOIN [cte_contact_invoice_summarized_totals] AS H ON
    H.[contact_id] = I.[contact_id] AND
    H.[invoice_id] = I.[invoice_id] AND
    H.[solution_id] = I.[solution_id]
  LEFT JOIN [cte_invoice_credit_dates] AS CD ON
    CD.[invoice_id] = I.[invoice_id]
  LEFT JOIN [credits] AS C ON
    C.[owner_id] = I.[contact_id] AND
    C.[date_applied] = CD.[date_applied]
ORDER BY
  I.[invoice_id],
  I.[solution_id];
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I'd upvote but as I'm fairly new I can't yet. My intention is that a customer would only have one active credit at any given time. Once used, the credit line would have an expiry date defined, ruling it out from subsequent invoices.

The join is hardcoded for brevity in this particular example, but yes, a proper join would be done to link the credit_id fields. 

Fortunately Im not having to worry about recording payments, these invoices are informational only (the totals sent to our finance dept to recover from cost centres internally).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have experienced a little and I will include a SQL sample in my answer for you to investigate somewhat further. (By the way, I don't think that you would need an extra column for an expiry date. If you need a new credit value, just add a new row. That credit value could be `0.00` if you want to cancel/expire the credit. Determining the active credit row is relatively easy by regarding the `date_applied` values for a specific contact/owner. And without an expiry date column, you will also avoid the risk of having overlapping credit values for a specific date.)

Comment: That makes sense, I'll drop the column.  Thanks for your expanded answer too, I'll see if I can use it :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use window functions, use a sub-query that sums the total of previous invoices. But be sure to use index the table correctly so that performance is not a problem.

There are two sub-queries, one for the previous total sum and another to get the date of the next credit for `contact_id`.

```
SELECT  [inv].[invoice_id],
        [inv].[solution_id],
        [inv].[total],
        -- subquery that sums the previous totals
        [cr].[total_applied] - COALESCE((
                                SELECT  SUM([inv_inner].[total])
                                FROM    [dbo].[invoices] AS [inv_inner]
                                WHERE [inv_inner].[solution_id] < [inv].[solution_id]
                            ), 0) AS [credit_available],
        [inv].[date]
FROM    [dbo].[invoices]        [inv]
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[credits]   [cr]
        ON [cr].[owner_id] = [inv].[contact_id]
        -- here, we make sure that the credit is available for the correct period
        -- invoice date >= credit date_applied
        AND [inv].[date] >= [cr].[date_applied]
        -- and invoice date < next date_applied or tomorrow, in case there are no next date_applied
        AND [inv].[date] < COALESCE((
                            SELECT  MIN([cr2].[date_applied])
                            FROM    [dbo].[credits] [cr2]
                            WHERE [cr2].[owner_id] = [cr].[owner_id]
                                AND [cr2].[date_applied] > [cr].[date_applied]
                        ), GETDATE()+1)
        AND [cr].[credit_id] = 'C00001';
```

This query works, but it is for this question only. Please study it and adapt to your real world problem.

Comment: Thank you Macros, I'll see if I can adapt it accordingly